# How to MVC correctly CoreData & NSDefaults

Tags: swift, core-data, model-view-controller, nsuserdefaults

I have a swift file called DataModel.swift that stores a struct.

My viewController.swift initialises a variable of type struct from the DataModel.swift. With that variable I can use the DataModel.swift to get values, calculate and return to the ViewController.swift

So far it works fine. But every-time the viewController.swift initialises the struct it also resets the struct. I would like this struct data to be persistent so when the user comes back the results are still there.

What would be the best way to resolve that?

Use core data?
Use NSUserDefaults?

I know how to store/read data on the ViewController using core-data or NSUserDefaults, but I am afraid if I do that I will end-up with all the code on the ViewController, which does not sound MVC to me.

Or is there a way store, loads and calculate the values keeping the code inside my DataModel.swift file?

Some samples of the code are bellow.

ViewController.swift struct initialisation bellow:

```
var calculations = ConcreteModel(
    width: 0,
    length: 0,
    thickness: 0,
    pricePerCubicMetre: 0,
    unit: "metric")
```

DataModel.swift file bellow:

```
struct ConcreteModel {
    var width: Double
    var length: Double
    var thickness: Double
    var pricePerCubicMetre: Double
    var unit: String

    init (
        width: Double,
        length: Double,
        thickness: Double,
        pricePerCubicMetre: Double, unit: String){

        self.width = width
        self.length = length
        self.thickness = thickness
        self.pricePerCubicMetre = pricePerCubicMetre
        self.unit = unit   
    }

    func gotVolume () -> Bool {
            return false
        }
    }

    func getVolume () -> Double {
        return calculation
    }

    func getCost () -> Double {
        return calculation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with your thinking. Put the code for persistence of your choice into the `DataModel` class.